# how do i remove whitespaces after parentheses in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

how to get the following outputs using reg-ex in javascript

```
input : "font1" font2 (____"font format"___)

output : "font1" font2 ("font format")

input : (___format____) / (___format) / (format_____)

output:(format)

input : (______"font-format"__)

output: ("font-format")

input:(__font

output:(font
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at the `\s` regular expression operator and what it does.

Comment: sorry,i am new to javascript and reg-ex any help would be appreciated?

Comment: I assume you are using `_` to represent whitespace here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hJ9qP1/1) for a single javascript regexp that allows you to eliminate blank space after ( and before ).

Comment: hey @luis.thanks for the answer and how can i learn building reg-ex statements in javascript.what are best resources..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In regular expressions, [`\s` matches any whitespace character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html). So given that, you can capture all of the whitespace preceding a `)` or following a `(` like this

```
(\()\s+|\s+(\))
```

then in Javascript you can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove them

```
var output = input.replace(/\(\s+|\s+\)/, '$1$2');
```

Comment: hi @mike.thanks for the reply.it is removing the first parentheses and unable to remove spaces also .if input: (  "font -format"  ) --> "font-format"   ) and i want like this --> ("font-format")

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex

```
(\(?)\s*([^\s]+)\s*(\)?)
```

in javascript

```
var output = input.replace(/(\(?)\s*([^\s]+)\s*(\)?)/gi, '$1$2$3');
```

Comment: hey @shaped it is removing the space between the words also input :(  "font format"  ) --> ("fontfomat") --> i need like --->("font format") .how to give exception to that

Comment: ok... `/(\(?)\s*(\w+|"[^"]+")\s*(\)?)/gi`. works for (   "font format"   ) but not (   font format  )

Comment: hey @shaped i have a string like --> "font1" font2 ( "font format" ) by using your regex i'm getting --->"font1"font2("fontformat") . but i need like this -->"font1" font2 ("font format") .i need to  remove spaces in parenthses only

Comment: to be hones: you changed the requirements three times. i gave you a solution matching your requirements two times... you have to specify exactly what you need...